# LshMatcher with opencv?

Tags: opencv, sift, matcher, orb

I am trying to use ORB descriptors with LshMatcher for a faster matching.

I have found somewhere LSH implementations (example: https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/browser/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/object_recognition_experimental/rbrief/src/lsh.cpp)

But it seems it is not implemented yet in opencv 2.4.2.

Do you have any hint how to include LshMatcher within opencv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have asked the same question on the OpenCV dev forum, without a good answer.

http://answers.opencv.org/question/503/how-to-use-the-lshindexparams/

Yet, I hope for some more docs. You can just check it again in a few days to see whether there is a new answer.

BTW, if you try to use it with SIFT/SURF/ORB, which are float descriptors, as I know, it will not work LSH are for binary descriptors only.

**Edit**

It seems to be a bug in OpenCV (2.4.2), as stated in the accepted answer here
http://answers.opencv.org/question/503/how-to-use-the-lshindexparams/

Comment: I saw that! :D Indeed i am posting a similar question there! let's hope for someone. Also I found this that is pretty intresting: http://code.google.com/p/find-object/source/browse/trunk/find_object/example/main.cpp basically in that code you can see that to use FLANN he makes a convertoTO CV_32F , but i believe isn't a good option

Comment: You can see my question regarding FLANN on opencv.org here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/503/how-to-use-the-lshindexparams/

Comment: i saw it! there is a bug! let's open a new issue on opencv.org!

Comment: Just be patient... OpenCV: Our website is temporarily unavailable due to system maintenance

Comment: Anyway I made that fix, now it's working. With 36 train images, the lsh with knnMatch took 0.4 sec... I believe it's a bit too much =/

Comment: when you get it working, please share a test with a dataset (100,500 train images) so we can compare the results (time performance)! Thanks a lot! If you are interested i am using a "google things" dataset of 500 images, you can find it here: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/background_google/google_things.tar